# AWS S3 with Java – Reactive

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-webflux

I want to upload multipart file like here [article](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/aws-modules/aws-reactive).
Here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
public Mono<ResponseEntity<UploadResult>> multipartUploadHandler(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestBody Flux<Part> parts) {

    return parts
            .ofType(FilePart.class) // We'll ignore other data for now
            .flatMap((part) -> saveFile(headers, s3config.getBucket(), part))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .map((keys) -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                    .body(new UploadResult(HttpStatus.CREATED, keys)));
}
```

But when I send a request, i get 415

[image: Postman]

What could be the problem?

Comment: (0. How to/who converts `Flux` parameter ??) 1. Why is it `@RequestBody`? (and not `@RequestPart` ..according to `consumes`) 2. Why `key=''` (empty string)?

Comment: can't change to `List<MultiPartFile>`, change to `@RequestPart` and send key say    _"message": "Content type 'image/tiff' not supported for bodyType=software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.Part"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `@RequestBody Flux<Part> parts` to `@RequestPart("file") Flux<FilePart> parts` fix all of this